# How to transfer file(s) from a Unix system to a DOS system?

Tags: linux, unix, file-transfer, ms-dos

What is the simplest way to transfer files from a Unix system to a DOS system? Preferably without any "extra" tools on the DOS side.

Comment: DOS as in obsolete since at least 1995?

Comment: if you don't want to install anything on the DOS side, you can try to install samba on Unix.

Comment: You might want to evaluate whether the time spent figuring out how to work with DOS is greater than the time spent rewriting whatever it does from scratch on a more modern operating system.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the ftp command, provided that you have a ftp server running on the Unix side.

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on what you consider "extra" tools on the DOS side.
Most versions of DOS came with no networking support at all, and required extra software to do networking.

So that pretty much limits your options to a floppy disk.  Both Unix and DOS natively support floppy discs, though you'll have to work out which file systems and file formats they both support.  FAT12 should be a safe bet at both ends.